# Update existing collection with new collection from same format

Tags: database, mongodb, lookup

I have a collection which is the main data collection, for simplicity, it's format is:

```
{item : 1, price: 10}, 
{item : 2, price : 20}
```

Once in a while I get a new data collection from the same format:

```
{item : 1, price: 123}, 
{item : 3, price : 30}
```

But I don't want to loose the former price and would like to create an accessible log within the collection.

> If the key already exists -> take the new price and create a log field.
>
> If the key doesn't exist -> add the new row/document to the main data collection as is.

So the desired output is something of the following:

```
{item : 1, price: 123, price_log: [{original_price : 10, change_date : {ISODate("2019-12-02T00:00:00.000+0000")}]}, 
{item : 2, price : 20}, 
{item : 3, price : 30}
```

I thought to do it with a double $lookup or something like that, but I'm sure there is a better approach which I'm not familier with since I'm new to MongoDB.

Comment: How often will there be an identical keys? The solution will depend on how long the log list will get.

Comment: more than 90% of the keys supposed to be existing in the main data collection

Comment: If you are most interested in the newest version, it might be easiest to follow [this post](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-document-versioning-pattern). This approach just creates a new document for every new version.

Comment: Unfortunately, I must save the old data as a field in the current collection.